# FullCalendar Within Twitter Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Has anyone managed to get FullCalendar working within Twitter Bootstrap 3 tabs ?

I've the following code;

```
<div class="tabbable">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li class="active"><a id="defaultTab" href="#tab_Default"><h5>Default</h5></a></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab_Default" class="tab-pane">
         @Html.Partial("_Calendar0")
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When this code is run I see the tab but no calendar content.

If I remove the 'class="tab-content"' from the second div then the tab and calendar displays ok but I'm not getting the tab functionality.

There's obviously some contention between the two pieces of software under the hood.
Anyone got a workaround ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Afraid I'll answer my own question (it's not against the rules is it ?);

The following code does the trick;

```html
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            $('#calendar0').fullCalendar('render');
            $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('render');
        });
        $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
    });

    <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li><a href="#tab_Default" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Default</h5></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_Choice1" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Choice 1</h5></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_Default" class="tab-pane">
            @Html.Partial("_Calendar0")
        </div>
        <div id="tab_Choice1" class="tab-pane">
            @Html.Partial("_Calendar1")
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The main problem was that FullCalendar won't load up a Calendar control if it's not on a displayed page.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Thanks for posting your solution. Just curious, why are you calling 'render' twice in the on event?

Comment: just noticed that you have two calendars....disregard previous comment. BTW your solution worked! Thanks again for posting this.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me a lot of hassle!

Answer (score 1):

Dunno why, but for me, using Fullcalendar3 & Bootstrap 4, I had to use :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    $('#calendar2').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me, not sure if this is proper, but after rendering do a click event on one of the timeline days or month views.

```
calendar.render();
$(".fc-resourceTimelineSevenDay-button").click();
```

or

```
calendar.render();
$(".fc-dayGridMonth-button").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    calendar.render();
});
```