# Bootstrap Tab-Pane with JS in it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery fullCalendar with Bootstrap Tabbed-Panels.

Only the first one works, others don't.

When I cancel the tabbed panels, everything works.

Here is my code.

`@foreach(something)
                <div class="tab-pane fade<?php if($count == 1) echo ' in active'; ?>">
                        <div class="panel panel-info">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="calendar{{ $count }}"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){

                            $('#calendar{{ $count }}').fullCalendar();
                        </script>
                </div>
@endforeach`

Comment: Seeing as the first one works, it sounds like an issue with unique ids of the calendar elements.

Comment: Looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803926/fullcalendar-within-twitter-bootstrap-tabs?rq=1 were the main problem was that FullCalendar won't load up a Calendar control if it's not on a displayed page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render fullcalendar unless it's visible.

Add a render call whenever you change tabs:

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/

```
$('#my-tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }
});
```