# FullCalendar view not showing on load

Tags: jquery, html, parse-platform, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar for a new site I working on. I have two divs with calendars attached. The first loads as expected...no issues. The second is the problem. It loads the header with buttons and title, but the view div is empty. I checked for errors, and none were thrown. If I click on the any header button the view is displayed as expected. I thought maybe it was a conflict between the two calendars, and it doesn't seem to be the issue. See the code below, and let me know your thoughts. I am using a Parse backend, which seems to be working just fine, and jQuery. Events call the same function for loading events and it also is working properly.

First calendar code:

```
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
            timezone: 'local',
            events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {        
                callback(getEvents(events, start, end));
            },
            color: 'lightBlue',
            textColor: 'gray',
            eventMouseover: function( calEvent, jsEvent, view ) {
                var $target = $(jsEvent.target).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                var location = userData.locations[calEvent.location.id];
                var event = userData.events[calEvent.eventData.id];
                var options = {
                    items: $target.parent(),
                    content: function() {
                        var info = "Event: <b>" + calEvent.title + "</b><br/><center>" + calEvent.description + "</center><br/>Date: " + moment(calEvent.start).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mma - ") + moment(calEvent.end).format("h:mma") + '<br/>Frequency: ' + event.get('eventFrequency') + '<br/> Frequency End Date: ' + moment(event.get('eventEndDate')).format('MM/DD/YY') + '<br/>Location: <center>' + location.get("locationName") + '<br/>' + location.get('locationAddress') + location.get('locationAddress2') + "<br>" + location.get('locationCity') + ', ' + location.get('locationState') + ' ' + location.get('locationCountry') + ' ' + location.get('locationPostalCode') + "</center><br/><center>Click Event to Edit";
                        return info;
                    }
                };
                $(view.el).tooltip(options);
            },
            eventMouseout: function( calEvent, jsEvent, view ) {
                $(view.el).tooltip('destroy');
            },
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                console.log(calEvent);
                console.log(jsEvent);
                console.log(view);
                userData.currentLocation = {};
                var location = userData.currentLocation['location'] = userData.locations[calEvent.location.id];
                var query = new Parse.Query('Event');
                query.equalTo('user', currentUser);
                query.equalTo('parent', location);
                query.find().then(function(events) {
                    userData.currentLocation.events = events;   
                    addRow(calEvent.eventData);
                    $('#add-location').text('Back to Calender').off().one('click',showCalendar);
                }, function(error) {
                    errorMessage(error);
                });
            },
            header: {
                left:   'title',
                center: '',
                right:  'today prev,next'
            },
            buttonIcons: {
                prev: 'left-single-arrow',
                next: 'right-single-arrow',
            },
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

            }
         });
```

Screenshot on load...works perfectly.

[image: Screenshot on load...works perfectly.]

Second calendar...not so much. Here's the code:

```
    $('#kp-agenda-view').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left:   'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right:  'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '05-05-2015',
            allDay: false,
            color: 'lightBlue',
            textColor: 'gray',
            timezone: 'local',
            overlap: false,
            editable: true,
            buttonIcons: {
                prev: 'left-single-arrow',
                next: 'right-single-arrow',
            },
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                callback(getEvents(userData.currentLocation.events, start, end));
            },
        })
```

[image: View Not Loaded]

After clicking any header button (I clicked 'today')...the view is loaded

[image: View Loaded after clicking a header button]

Not really sure what's going on, and I can't seem to find any similar entries on the web. Thanks in advance, and let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: what if you remove all the options from `$('#kp-agenda-view').fullCalendar()` , will it still load?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a bit too late but take a look at this question:
[FullCalendar Within Twitter Bootstrap Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803926/fullcalendar-within-twitter-bootstrap-tabs)
It seems that the fullcalendar won't load if it is in an element that is not displayed. If this is the case the simple 'shotgun' solution is to force rendering via

```
$('#kp-agenda-view').fullCalendar('render');
```

when the calendar gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue when i saw this post.
The solution above, which means to invocate the render, don't worked for me.

The only way that i found to make this work was turn, in my case, the div invisible where the calendar was placed, into visible, before the original render of the calendar and then, make invisible again.

Answer (score 1):

What we did, is copy all the code for the first Calendar, and pasted that code below the original code, and renamed all Calendar references to Calendar2.  This includes the div for the second calendar on the same page.

Some JS:

```
// Calendar 2 beginning
    var calendarioDiv2 = $('#calendar2');
    var fullCalendar = calendarioDiv2.fullCalendar({......)}

//last lines fo JS

$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    $('#calendar2').fullCalendar('render');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A little workaround, before call fullCalendar method

```
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#kp-agenda-view').fullCalendar('render');
    });
```

it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Working of me

```
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#kp-agenda-view').fullCalendar('render');
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. My problem was in tab container rendering animation. According to the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/), method `fullcalendar.render()` tries to render calendar grid in visible container only. So, if you fire `fullcalendar.render()` immediately after tab click but do have some animation on tab container, where calendar is being rendered (for example "fade in" animation, which obviously takes some time to execute), then be ready to catch tab container without calendar grid.

Or this case, solution will be similar to this:

```
$("#calendarTab").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#fullCalendar").fullCalendar("render");
    }, 300); // Set enough time to wait until animation finishes;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. (In my case calendar was placed in invisible div)
Solution: Before rendering the calendar, show the calendar. And hide calendar once calendar renders.

Comment: It seems more like a comment than an answer. Please write something more, otherwise, it will be closed soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {  height: 300,
      plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
      header    : {
        left  : 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right : 'dayGridMonth'
      },

I just give a height then my issue is solved.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the view that was containing calendar div was dynamically added using ajax and jQuery. And the calendar (FullCalendar) was not loading/ rendering for the first time.

But, when I was doing inspect the element, it was immediately rendered.

I used setTimeOut and it worked. The working code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    //Until the data was not rendered. I was showing a loader to engage the users. Just you need to change the image path
    showLoader("#lxgEventsCalendar");

    //Creating a delay of 500 ms
    setTimeout(function () {
        loadFullCalData();
    }, 500);

});

function loadFullCalData() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('lxgEventsCalendar');

    var calEvents = [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2021-11-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2021-11-07',
            end: '2020-11-10'
        },
        {
            groupId: '999',
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2021-11-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            groupId: '1',
            title: 'Meetings with Share Holders',
            start: '2021-11-14T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            groupId: '2',
            title: 'Meeting with Sam & Co',
            start: '2021-11-15T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            groupId: '3',
            title: 'Meeting with MDT Polymers',
            start: '2021-11-19T16:00:00'
        }];

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {

            center: 'title',
            start: 'today prev,next',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },

        dateClick: function (info) {

            var markup = "<div class=\"form-horizontal\"><div class=\"form-group\"><label class=\"control-label col-lg-3\">Date Selected</label> <div class=\"col-lg-6\">" + info.dateStr + "</div> </div></div>";
            showAlert(info.dateStr);
        },
        events: calEvents
    });

    calendar.render();
}

function showLoader(divSelector) {
       var loaderMarkup = "<div id='imgLoader' class='loader-img' style='width: 100%;margin: 0px auto 0px auto; padding: 10px 0; text-align:center;overflow: hidde;'><img style='margin: 0px auto 0px auto;' src='../../images/waiting_animation_circle.gif'/></div>";


    $(divSelector).html(loaderMarkup);
}

</script>


<div id='lxgEventsCalendar' class="col-lg-12"></div>
```